# How do I make a cluster with similar type of skills together?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

Suppose that I have a file which has thousands of skills starting from A-Z. Now, I would like to create a model that can group similar skills together (example neural network and SVM can group together). I know that I can use NLP for this problem, but I'm not sure about the algorithm that I can use to get the best result.

I'm new to NLP so any help is greatly appreciated.

I was thinking at first to use semantic similarity. So I can use pre-trained word embeddings to map the words to a new vector space where I can calculate the distance between the word embeddings, e.g. with word2vec or other implementations. But I'm not sure about this. Can you give me some link or show me how do I do it so I can get a best result? Take a look at the data[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGRI0.png

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 36943 entries, 0 to 36942
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Skills    36942 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 288.7+ KB
None
                   Skills
0                    .NET
1                .NET CLR
2  .NET Compact Framework
3          .NET Framework
4           .NET Remoting
```

Answer (score 0):

To your situation, one of the best options could be Kohonen Neural Network. Although, you need to normalise the data according to supervised learning, but you can get everything related to your requirement in link below:
http://www.kovera.org/neural-network-for-clustering-in-python/

Comment: I want to understand something here so I don't have to use NLP here? If I follow this procedure

Comment: And also can we use K-means clustering algorithm?

Comment: NLP is an approach to process behavioural, patterns or predictions in terms of linguistics. But to achieve, that you need to use models or classifiers. Although, you can use naive bayes classifier too instead of kohonen, all depends upon your experience, level of accuracy.

Comment: You can use k-means algorithm too for clustering and there are alot of resources available and support libraries including sklearn in python. Although, i still think, if you have less experience implementing these, kohonen can be the fastest in implementing. I hope it helps you.